# Symfony 3+ : Styling the parent div of a field (div containing label + input)

Tags: forms, symfony, styles

At first, my objective here is to make two input fields inline, the picture is attached :

[image]

Symfony allow us to style form's field by using **attr** for form_widget of the field and **label_attr** for form_label but here i want to apply a style for the div containing the label + input that Symfony generate automatically in the twig :

```
$builder
->add('language', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices'  => array(
        'FR' => 5,
        'EN' => 1,
     ),
    'label'      => ' ',
    'attr' => array('style' => 'float:left;width:40%'),
))
->add('level', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices'  => array(
        'Good' => 5,
        'Bad' => 1,
     ),
    'label'      => ' ',
    'attr' => array('style' => 'float:left;width:40%'),
));
```

result : The style has been applyed to the input (select in our case) and the div parent wasn't be affected (stay with empty style):

```
<div id="homebundle_personnel_personnelLanguages_0">
   <div> <!-- the div that i want to apply a style -->
      <label for="homebundle_personnel_personnelLanguages_0_language" class="required"> </label>
      <select id="homebundle_personnel_personnelLanguages_0_language" name="homebundle_personnel[personnelLanguages][0][language]" style="float:left;width:40%">
         <option value="5">FR</option>
         <option value="1">EN</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div>
      <label for="homebundle_personnel_personnelLanguages_0_level" class="required"> </label>
      <select id="homebundle_personnel_personnelLanguages_0_level" name="homebundle_personnel[personnelLanguages][0][level]" style="float:left;width:40%">
         <option value="5">Good</option>
         <option value="1">Bad</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
'row_attr' => [
    'class' => 'yourClass',
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved, I must treat this in the twig's level :

```
<div style="float:left;width:40%" >
    {{ form_widget(form.language) }}
</div>

<div style="float:left;width:40%" >
    {{ form_widget(form.level) }}
</div>
```